# XNA 3D/WP7 point light without custom shader

Tags: wpf, 3d, xna, light

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a point light in XNA without writing a custom shader (because WP7 doesn't support this) using only directional light from the basic effect.

Has anyone tried this before?

Comment: A very blunt solution would be creating several directional lights around a point. With just a few the effect could be good enough, but I'm not sure how bad it would be for performance.

Comment: Check that: http://www.catalinzima.com/tutorials/deferred-rendering-in-xna/point-lights/

Comment: From your page: "We begin by writing a new effect file for this, named PointLight.fx."
My question: "without writing a custom shader (because WP7 doesn't support this)"

Or do you mean something else on this page?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it will not cast shadow.
The light can be created in BasicEffect, by editing DirectionalLight# propriety.
You can also use BasicEffect.enableDefaultLightning() in order to rapidly create a light.